# Java BlockingQueue take vs poll

Tags: java

I'm running a process where:

- If there's an item in the queue, the item should be processed.
- There should be at least one item processed every 5 minutes. If there isn't, a dummy item is added.

I'm thinking of using a BlockingQueue to accomplish this - it offers the functions `take()` and `poll(timeout, timeunit)` to do this.

With `take` I would simply have a `while(item = queue.take()){ process(item); }`. There would be a second thread running that would add a dummy item to the queue every 5 minutes, so that every 5 minutes it is guaranteed that at least this one dummy item is processed.

With `poll` I would do

```
while(true){
    item = queue.poll(5L, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    if(item == null) item = 'dummyitem';
    process(item);
}
```

Is there a difference between these approaches, which one is better?

Comment: If you do (2) you're not relying on someone else adding the dummy item, whatever the point of that may be.

Comment: The approach with take() would just hang if there was nothing in the queue,  until there was something. Can your calling process tolerate this waiting for 5 minutes at a time?

Comment: I'm leaning for `poll` as well, just wasn't sure. @paisanco this while loop would be running in its own thread as well so it shouldn't interfere with anything.